# Error with stack in assembly 8086 (real mode) (printing char while stack full)

Tags: assembly, printing, x86, stack, x86-16

so I have written a little program to write a number higher than 9 to the screen. But as soon as I push a value to stack, I can't print a thing until the stack is empty. Is there a way to go around this?

Here is the code:

```
print_int:          ; Breaks number in ax register to print it
    mov cx, 10
    mov bx, 0
    break_num_to_pics:
        cmp ax, 0
        je print_all_pics
        div cx
        push dx
        inc bx
        jmp break_num_to_pics
    print_all_pics:
        cmp bx, 0       ; tests if bx is already null
        je f_end
        pop ax
        add ax, 30h
        call print_char
        dec bx
        jmp print_all_pics

print_char:             ; Function to print single character to      screen
        mov ah, 0eh     ; Prepare registers to print the character
        int 10h         ; Call BIOS interrupt
        ret

f_end:              ; Return back upon function completion
    ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 bugs in your code.

The first one is is that you don't zero `dx` before `div cx`:

```
print_int:          ; Breaks number in ax register to print it
    mov cx, 10
    mov bx, 0
    break_num_to_pics:
    cmp ax, 0
    je print_all_pics

    ; here you need to zero dx, eg. xor dx,dx

    xor dx,dx       ; add this line to your code.

    div cx          ; dx:ax/cx, quotient in ax, remainder in dx.
    push dx         ; push remainder into stack.
    inc bx          ; increment counter.
    jmp break_num_to_pics
```

The problem is that you don't zero `dx` before division. The first time `div cx`, `dx` is uninitialized. The next time `div cx` is reached `remainder:quotient` gets divided by `10`, and that does not make much sense.

The other one is here:

```
print_char:         ; Function to print single character to      screen
    mov ah, 0eh     ; Prepare registers to print the character
    int 10h         ; Call BIOS interrupt
    ret
```

You don't set any meaningful values to `bl` and `bh`, even if those are input registers of
`mov ah,0eh`, `int 10h` (see [Ralf Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm))

```
INT 10 - VIDEO - TELETYPE OUTPUT
     AH = 0Eh
     AL = character to write
     BH = page number
     BL = foreground color (graphics modes only)
```

As you use `bx` as a counter, you need to store it either inside or outside `print_char`. For example, saving `bx` inside `print_char`:

```
print_char:         ; Function to print single character to      screen
    mov ah, 0eh     ; Prepare registers to print the character

    push bx         ; store bx into stack
    xor bh,bh       ; page number <- check this, if I remember correctly 0
                    ; is the default page.
    mov bl,0fh      ; foreground color (graphics modes only)

    int 10h         ; Call BIOS interrupt

    pop bx          ; pop bx from stack
    ret
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this later today. I did noticed about the dx, once I tried printing values in reverse (so 9573 becomes 3759, since this would also accomplish what I need print_int function for), HOWEVER, I did not know about the bx thing. So thanks for that.